# Is casein protein in cow milk as good as casein powders?

Tags: protein, milk

Milk has an 80:20 casein:whey protein ratio according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk).

> There are four different types of casein proteins, and collectively
>   they make up around 80% of the protein in milk

Can skim cow milk be effectively used as a pre-bedtime drink for slow release of casein protein as one sleeps? Do casein protein powders found in health stores offer any advantages over skim milk?

Comment: I'm not yet familiar enough with the details of casein to make an answer, but why do you specify skim milk? Whole milk is generally the drink of choice among lifters of all sorts.

Comment: Because I'm trying to [gain muscle and lose fat at the same time](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3291/how-to-lose-fat-and-gain-muscle-at-the-same-time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find this article by [Tom Venuto](http://www.tomvenuto.com/articles/protein_supplements.shtml) interesting esp. since you want to gain muscle and lose fat at the same time which is basically what his book, Burn the Fat, Feed the Muscle is about. It is a long article that discusses proteins, and food vs supplements. In general, he writes that:

> Aside from convenience, the truth about protein supplements is that they offer few advantages over protein foods. There is no scientific evidence that you can't meet all of your protein needs for muscle growth through food

(as long as you are getting your complete proteins with every meal).

He also has an [article about milk](http://blog.holygrailbodytransformation.com/?p=146) (and chocolate milk) as part of your body recomposition program.

> Surprisingly to many people, dairy proteins keep coming up winners. In fact, numerous studies have suggested that good old milk is excellent for both post workout protein as well as re-hydration.

It sounds like you are on the right track with your low fat milk.