# Good diet for losing fat and gaining muscle at the same time?

Tags: weight-loss, muscle

I have lurked this site for a bit and [this](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3291/how-to-lose-fat-and-gain-muscle-at-the-same-time) question basically showed me that for people who are obese it is possible to be losing fat and gaining muscle at the same time.

I have experienced this myself; a couple of years ago, when I was obese, I decided to lose weight. I also frequented the gym and I found that I was losing weight and gaining muscle (mainly biceps). As I lost more weight I even started seeing a six pack and after about 7 months I achieved my goal; I lost weight and I had a body I found aesthetically pleasing. Unfortunately for me though, a couple of weeks after achieving my goal I got into an accident which sidelined me for months and kept me from training intensively for a year or so. The weight piled on (which was my fault, I picked up on an unhealthy diet) and now I'm back to square one. I started going to the gym again recently and I wanted to start again, and I was wondering what the best diet would be for losing fat and gaining muscle quickly?

- I gain muscle very quickly and I lose fat very quickly too, however, I also gain fat quickly.

I used to just go for a calorie deficit everyday, but I'm wondering what kind of diet would be optimal for this (in terms of meat, vegetables, fish, etc.)

Comment: @FredrikD I friggen mentioned that in my question itself.

Comment: Doesn't the linked post answer the question?

Comment: @ZafarS - maybe you should friggen read it again. It answers your question.

Comment: @JohnP I'm expecting a bit more detailed answer..

Comment: If you want a more detailed answer you should not re-ask the question but put a bounty on the other one. OR you should explicitly state what the other question doesn't answer and make your question more specific in that certain aspect.

Comment: I did, read the last sentence.